# HTTP traffic captureUbuntu 12.10 on VMware

Tags: html

I am trying to capture and regenerate http traffic over the network. i have a basice sniffer program but it captures everything i have limited the traffic using port 80. but the problem starts when it keeps on capturing the icmp, dns and arp requests too. basically my project is to do the equivalent of "save as" in a browser. but i have to achieve that usng the sniffer. the idea is to append the data payload in packets using fprint as i am using c to write this. can anyone help me with this code please. its the last hurdle between me and my graduation.
regards
Adam

Comment: Is your code posted anywhere that might be viewable? (Github/etc)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.circlemud.org/jelson/software/tcpflow/

I didn't know you could graduate with things like this.